# Disable sound just for one application

Tags: android, audio, preferences

Is it possible to turn off all sounds of just one app and to save the choice until the next start of the app?

So I have a ToggleButton at the StartActivity and by pressing this Button, all sounds of the app should be deactivated, but sounds of other apps should still be working.

I tried it with Preferences, using the SharedPreferences class, an xml file and so on, like in my book. But going through the introduction i realized, that the Preferences are just a way to save data permanent. **So I would have to include for example on every Button with a sound an if-clause that checks if this or that saved preference for sound on/off is true/false and then activates/deactivates the sound?**

I thought that it could be easier?

Comment: Just for clarity, you are wanting to do this programatically, from inside the app that you want to be quiet, or are you wanting to force this behavior on another app?

Comment: I want this just inside the app, so if I muted the sound in my app, others app-sounds should still be on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you want to disable a sound in your application - you can just don't play it. You can store the flags for each sound you want to play in the `SharedPreferences` and check it every time you want to play a sound. It's really easy!

Comment: Ok, so you meant that I have to store only one attribute in the SharedPreferences. And then I have to set in every onClickListener an if-clause around the command to play the sound or to not play it?

Comment: @robinson1, Yes, you're right. You have to store one boolean value for every sound you play, or just one value, if it's the global sound flag in your application. If it's false - you just don't play a sound, that's all.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now setting a soundcall into an if-clause which checks out if the general soundsetting is checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably write your own MyButton class that extends Button and override onClick.

Comment: Could also work, thanks. But I've solved it now with an if-clause around every button that plays a sound.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a string

   `String strSound;`
2. enter this line in your shared preference settings

   strSound = prefs.getString("sound", "on");
3. enter this line in your `onActivityResult`

   `strSound = prefs.getString("sound", "on");`
4. put this lines in your media player which is used to give sounds for your application

   ```
   private void playSound()
   {
   mp = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this, R.raw."your_soundfile_name");

   mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
   {
       @Override
       public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
       {
           mp.release();
       }
   }); 
   if(strSound.equals("on"))
   mp.start();
   ```
5. now put this lines on your toggle button activity

   ```
   your_togglebutton_id.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new     CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
   {
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
       {
           prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
           if (isChecked)
           {
               editor.putString("sound", "on");
               editor.commit();
           }
           else
           {
               editor.putString("sound", "off");
               editor.commit();
           }
       }
   }
   ```