# How do I globally disable the sounds within an Android application?

Tags: java, android, mobile, audio

I currently have a checkbox to correctly determine if the sound on/off toggle is pressed, and I save the preferences so that I can globally access the mPrefs later in all my activities.

I've been searching for how to disable global sounds within my application but couldn't come to a conclusion.

Is there any example or tutorial that goes through this process?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236678/disable-sound-just-for-one-application

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317974/android-mute-unmute-phone) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895882/mute-the-global-sound-in-android).